# How do I convert a array into a integre using int(a[i]) in python

Tags: python, arrays, integer

I have this code in Python3.4:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import pickle, os

global sec
sec = [0]
sec[0] = 0
file2 = open('sec.dat', 'wb')
pickle.dump(sec[0], file2)
file2.close()

global end
end = False

window = Tk()
window.configure(bg='green')
c = Canvas(window, width=200, height=200, bg='green')
c.pack()
data = [0]
data[0] = True

file = open('pickle.dat', 'wb')
pickle.dump(sec, file)
file.close()

sec[0] = 0

def pause():
    btnpause.configure(state=DISABLED)
    btnunpause.configure(state=NORMAL)
    pause = True

    file3 = open('pause.dat','wb')
    pickle.dump(pause,file3)
    file3.close()


def stop():
    data[0] = False
    file = open('pickle.dat', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data,file)
    file.close()


def unpause():
    pass


def start(event):
    btn.configure(state = NORMAL)
    btnpause.configure(state = NORMAL)
    WIDTH = 200
    HEIGHT = 200

    file2 = open('sec.dat','rb')
    sec = pickle.load(file2)
    file2.close()

    while True:
        key = event.keysym
        sleep(1)
        sec[0] += 1
        min1 = sec * 60
        print(min1)
        print(counter)
        time_text = c.create_rectangle(WIDTH, HEIGHT, -WIDTH, -HEIGHT, fill='green')
        time_text = c.create_text(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, text=str(sec), fill='white', font=('Droid Serif', 16))
        window.update()
        file = open('pickle.dat', 'rb')
        data = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()

        if data[0] == False:
             break

c.bind_all('<Key>', start)
btn = Button(window, text='stop', command=stop, bg='lightblue')
btnpause = Button(window, text='pause', command=pause, bg='lightblue')
btnunpause = Button(window,text='unpause', command=unpause, bg='lightblue')
btnpause.pack()
btn.pack()
btnunpause.pack()
btnunpause.configure(state=DISABLED)
btn.configure(state=DISABLED)
btnpause.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

And it came up with an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/idlelib/run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
     File "/home/james/Desktop/Python/The-finished-stopwatch2.py", line 47, in start
       sec[0] += 1
   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

And I was trying to make the array an int but it came up with that error.

Comment: Just as a comment, 'sec[0] = 0` does not modify `sec` at all, because `sec = [0]` does the exact same thing. You don't need that second line.

Comment: This made it shorter :) but it didn't solve the problem! Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I think you need to get rid of all code not relevant to this question, and it would be much easier to help. Try to only include the lines wehre the error occurs, and any lines that initialize variables in those lines.

Comment: I thought about doing that but I thought the code would get more responses if everyone knew what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 8 you dump `sec[0]`, the integer, not the array. This integer was undumped in line 42 as `sec`.

Simply write:

```
sec += 1
```

and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks but it only counts up 1 then stops

Comment: That's because you always reload `sec`.

Answer (score 0):

**Trying to make array an int.** If I understood your question correctly, what you need is this:

```
lst = ["1", "2", "3"]
print map(int, lst)
```

Which gives you

```
[1, 2, 3]
```